# Is it possible to parse emojis using spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, emoji, spacy

Is it possible to tokenize emojis like `:)`, `:(`, `;~(` properly using the spaCy Python library? e.g. If I run the following code:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp("Hello bright world :)")
```

And then visualize the doc with [displaCy](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers):

[image]

It incorrectly parses `world :)` as one token. How can I modify spaCy so it recognizes these additional symbols? Thanks.

**edit:** Found the following: https://github.com/ines/spacymoji but I think it only supports Unicode emojis like ✨ and not ASCII ones like `:)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, spaCy actually includes a pretty comprehensive [list of text-based emoticons](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/tokenizer_exceptions.py#L81) as part of its tokenizer exceptions. So using your example above and printing the individual tokens, the emoticon is tokenized correctly:

```
doc = nlp("Hello bright world :)")
print([token.text for token in doc])
# ['Hello', 'bright', 'world', ':)']
```

I think what happens here is that you actually came across an interesting (maybe non-ideal) edge case with the `displacy` defaults. To avoid very long dependency arcs for punctuation, the [`collapse_punct` setting](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#options-dep) defaults to `True`. This means that when the visualisation is rendered, punctuation is merged onto the preceding token. Punctuation is identified by checking whether the token's `is_punct` attribute returns `True` – which also happens to be the case for ":)".

In your example, you can work around this by setting `collapse_punct` to `False` in the options passed to `displacy.serve`:

```
displacy.serve(doc, style='dep', options={'collapse_punct': False})
```

(The displaCy visualizer should probably include an exception for emoticons when merging punctuation. This is currently difficult, because spaCy doesn't have an `is_emoji` or `is_symbol` flag. However, it might be a nice addition in the future – you can vote for it [on this thread](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1439).)

Answer (score 2):

Now it seems to be possible.
You need to install the spacymoji module first. [Here](https://github.com/ines/spacymoji) are the instructions.
You can check whether a list of tokens has any emoji, or a specific token is_emoji, and there are some other useful functions.

spacymoji requires spaCy v2.0.0 or higher.

```
pip install spacymoji
```

The following example is taken from the git page. But you can find more comprehensive explanation using the spacymoji extension with spaCy in [this blog](https://explosion.ai/blog/spacy-v2-pipelines-extensions#spacymoji).

```
import spacy
from spacymoji import Emoji

nlp = spacy.load('en')
emoji = Emoji(nlp)
nlp.add_pipe(emoji, first=True)

doc = nlp(u"This is a test  ")
assert doc._.has_emoji == True
assert doc[2:5]._.has_emoji == True
assert doc[0]._.is_emoji == False
assert doc[4]._.is_emoji == True
....
```

Hope this helps someone in future...

Comment: This is great! However, this does not detect text-based emojis e.g. ":-)". So, it is best to supplement this by adding a Pipeline component that detects the text-based emoticons list from `spacy.lang.tokenizer_exceptions`.